# Is there syntax highlighting for Java getters and setters in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

Is there a setting that would colour Java getters and setters differently than ordinary methods in IntelliJ? Similar to how `Structure` window has a `Show Properties` toggle to group them separately. May be even go as far as de-emphasising `get` and `set` parts like the crude mockup below.

[image]

Comment: I love this idea. Eclipse, too!

Comment: Usually colors for a specfic language can be defined via Preference/Editor/Color & Fonts/Java, though the list of colorable options does not specify getters or setters. Therefore probably a custom coloring plugin will be needed, similar to [the sample provided by Jetbrains](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Syntax+Highlighter+and+Color+Settings+Page)

Comment: I don't think there is such setting in IntelliJ and I haven't encountered plugin for this either. But I like the idea! If you decide to open a feature request on youtrack.jetbrains.com, share a link so we can subscribe and vote for it :)

Comment: Done: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144466

Comment: This seems like a bit of an anti-pattern.  The whole purpose of getters and setters is to *hide* the fact that there are fields with the same names; a feature that exposes whether a method is tied to a field or not feels... strange.

Comment: @dimo414 I always thought it's to hide that anything other than assignment is happening (e.g. validation, logging, etc). I still would like getFullName to be highlighted even though there is no fullName field and all it does is concatenates firstName and lastName fields.

Comment: So you just want to highlight methods that start with `get` or `set` differently from other methods?

Comment: @dimo414 personally yes, I disagree with the way the ticket above is phrased about only being applicable to "simple" accessors. If they make it configurable I would colour "with" methods differently as well to highlight the builders, and some other global prefixes.